# Encode string javascript so that it can be transmitted to a server

Tags: javascript, json, jqgrid

I'm trying to send json string in the get request to the server, here is how it looks before encoding :

```
filters={"groupOp":"AND","rules":[{"field":"countrycode","op":"eq","data":"ARG"}]}
```

Naturally I end up with null pointer when trying to get this json string, then I googled this encodeURIComponent and it partially encodes this string like this :

```
filters={"groupOp"%3A"AND"%2C"rules"%3A[{"field"%3A"countrycode"%2C"op"%3A"eq"%2C"data"%3A"ARG"}]}
```

But this is how it supposed to be in order to work :

```
filters=%7B%22groupOp%22%3A%22AND%22%2C%22rules%22%3A%5B%7B%22field%22%3A%22countrycode%22%2C%22op%22%3A%22eq%22%2C%22data%22%3A%22ARG%22%7D%5D%7D
```

How do I get this, entirely encoded string so I can read it at server side properly ?

**Reason why I used get instead of post**

I'm sending this filter(json) content to the server side, web service gets data from the database and returns pdf document.

Using post, I'm able to send correct data and the response is successfully displayed in my firebug console. But I need to return pdf doc to override the current page or open new window/tab and return in that one.

Comment: What are you sending where exactly?

Comment: Maybe he's looking for `JSON.stringify`.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal @ server side I'm using spring mvc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're overworking this problem. Or encoding too many times.  Or something.
You've got a JSON string, and you are trying to JSON encode it. That seems...unhelpful.

A better approach might be to produce a Javascript object, then JSON.Stringify *that*, and then transmit it as a parameter.

```
var thing = {
  groupOp : "AND",
  rules : [
    { field : "countrycode", op : "eq", data : "ARG" },
      ...
  ],
    ...
}; 
var stringrep = JSON.stringify(thing);
// post via jQuery
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: url,
  data: stringrep,
  dataType: 'json'
  success: function() { ... },
});
```

Normally for a JSON stringified message to or from the server, you'd want to use HTTP POST. HTTP GET puts all "parameters" in the URL; there is no message body.  In contrast, HTTP POST allows you to attach a message body to the HTTP message, which can be "anything".  With that approach, you don't need to url-encode the quotes and spaces; the JSON message just gets transmitted as the message body of the HTTP message.

HTTP POST is the way applications upload images, or transmit XML documents, and so on. Anything complex gets transmitted via POST.

Comment: I like your answer, where you don't have to encode anything to POST. But thing is that I need to return the pdf document, that is why I used get, so I populate it with certain data. So I get back rendered pdf doc, with post the request returns success response, and I can see it in firebug. I need it to open in new page or override the current one.

Comment: I don't understand; if what you are saying is that you need to get a response, you can certainly receive a response from a POST message, and the response may be a PDF document. Using post makes sense if you have a bunch of data to send to the server, that it needs to produce the response, whatever the response is.

Comment: tnx, I got it now, it looks really elegant without all of those get arguments, and no need to encode them as well

Answer (score 4):

```
var filtersParameter = 'filters=' + encodeURI(JSON.stringify(filters));
```

Comment: nop that produces `filters="{\"groupOp\":\"AND\",\"rules\":[{\"field\":\"countrycode\",\"op\":\"eq\",\"data\":\"ARG\"}]}"`

Comment: Don't forget `encodeURI()`. If I run that, I get: `filters=%7B%22groupOp%22:%22AND%22,%22rules%22:%5B%7B%22field%22:%22countrycode%22,%22op%22:%22eq%22,%22data%22:%22ARG%22%7D%5D%7D`

Comment: are you gonna put that in the URL?  I think I just threw up on my shoes.

Comment: POST is way better than GET for these kinds of situations.

Comment: 2018 here .. I also threw up all over my shirt

Answer (score 1):

```
var filtersParameter = 'filters=' + atob(JSON.stringify(filters));
```

Note: `atob()` method uses **base64** algorithm to encode the data. This encoded data can be easily passed to a server where it can be decoded using corresponding decoding methods (in python `base64.b64decode(encoded_string)` is used).